# Recovering files from partition (ext4)

Tags: debian, data-recovery, ext4

a part of out homework assignment is to recover deleted files from the partition with the ext4 file system.

I've tried using the extundelete tool, by following [this](http://garbers.co.za/2010/12/15/recovering-recently-deleted-files-from-an-ext3ext4-with-journaling-partition/) tutorial. The tool recovered a lot of files, which couldn't be opened, so I guess this doesn't do me any good.

Is there any other tool I could try, to recover the deleted files, or is this tool the best there is? I didn't write anything to the partition, before the recovery process, and I recovered the files to another partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use software that risk modifying the deleted partition you should first make an image of the disk using `dd`, `dd_rescue` or the like.

When it comes to tools you could try out [TestDisk and PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Main_Page). TestDisk, now at [version 6.13](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_6.13_Release) has had support for ext4 since [version 6.11](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_6.11_Release).

[TestDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk) is gained towards partition recovery, whilst [PhotoRec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec) uses [file carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_carving).

If platform is not an issue you could also have a look at e.g. [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/). Beside TestDisk and PhotoRec v 6.14b it has a long list of other nice tools. Look under e.g. *"Hard Disk Tools"* and *"Recovery Tools"* (expanded by `See CD Contents »` on above link.)